# Connect to ejabberd server and application server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, xmpp, ejabberd

I have an [ejabberd](https://www.ejabberd.im/) server and I am trying to build a chat module in my [Angular](https://angularjs.org/)/[NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/) app.

Currenlty, my `Angular` app connects directly to the chat server. Assume my `roster` has 100 contacts comprising of `online` and `offline` contacts. I need to map all the 100 contacts with the users in my application server to get more details like `companyId`, `email`, `contact`, etc.

Do I have to loop through each contact and call an API to the application server? Wouldn't that put a lot of load on the frontend? Is there a better way of achieving this?

Apologies if my question is silly. I am new to `XMPP`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several way´s of doing this.

You could go and fetch every single user from your API, cache them so the next you don´t have to fetch all the data, but that´s not the optimal solution.

The other solution would be to get all contacts with one single call by passing all id´s to your node application. Then the node app can fetch all needed data from your database and pass it back with one Request and not 100.

Answer (score 0):

With more or less the same problem I used a jabber search getting up all the users and stored on client for the entire session.

My requsite it's "all users can chat with all other users" (about 100 users on server),

if your is not, I suggest you to create a custom IQ and let server cache the Jabber search (updating after each user registration) and reply with only required datas in a single call, async.